# Error: spawn EACCES in Node AWS Lambda function using child_process to call a binary file

Tags: node.js, permissions, aws-lambda

I have this simplified code in a Node-based AWS Lambda function:

```
import { execFile } from 'child_process';
execFile('./node_modules/webp/bin/dwebp', ['./tmp/file.wepb', '-o', 
'./tmp/newFile.png'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) throw error;
});
```

As shown, I have a binary file in `node_modules/webp/bin` and I'm calling it with `execFile` to save an output in the folder `./tmp/` but I'm getting the error `Error: spawn EACCES`. Probably I'm not denied to access the folder `./tmp/` because my code is successfully writing files in it. I might be only denied to access to command `dwebp` itself. I don't know how to handle it. Hope you can help.

Comment: Writing to the folder means you have write permissions. You still might be lacking execution permissions.

Comment: Also, you can edit permissions using node with the `chmod` command from the `fs` module. [You can read about it here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmod_path_mode_callback)

Comment: @daviscodesbugs Thank you! Using `fs.chmodSync()` did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer since it seemed to be the solution to your problem.

Writing to the folder means you have write permissions. You still might be lacking execution permissions.

You can edit permissions within Node using the `chmod` from the `fs` module. [Documentation can be found here.](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmod_path_mode_callback)